# How to mock the method of an object in which mocks are injected

Tags: java, testng, mockito

I am writing tests for a class using mockito and testng. The class to be tested has several dependencies which need to be mocked and injected. The class to be tested has the following profile

```
class A{
    @Autowired
    private Object1;
    @Autowired
    private Object2;
    Object3 methodToBeTested (){
           //some code
           method2();
           //some code
    }
    boolean method2(){
        //some calls to Database that are not operational
    }
}
```

In my test class, I am declaring the objects Object1 and Object2 as mocks and initializing them as below

```
@Mock
Object1 ob1;
@Mock
Object2 ob2;
@InjectMocks
A a = new A();

@Test
public void ATest(){
     Object3 ob3;
     when(ob1.someMethod()).thenReturn(someObject);
     when(ob2.someMethos()).thenReturn(someOtherObject);
     ob3 = a.methodToBeTested();
     assertNotNull(ob3);
}
```

The problem arises because I have to mock the call to method2 of class A as well as it has some calls that are not operational in testing phase. Also mockito does not allow an object to have both @Mocks and @InjectMocks  annotations simultaneously. Is there a way to move forward with the testing without modifying code for Class A (don't want to modify it just for testing).

Comment: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Comment: @JBNizet Want to make that an answer so I can upvote it?  Obviously, it's correct.

Comment: @DavidWallace Done. Thanks for making me less lazy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to spy on the real A object, as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13):

```
@Mock
Object1 ob1;

@Mock
Object2 ob2;

@InjectMocks
A a = new A();

@Test
public void ATest(){
    A spy = spy(a);

    doReturn(true).when(spy).method2();

    Object3 ob3;
    when(ob1.someMethod()).thenReturn(someObject);
    when(ob2.someMethos()).thenReturn(someOtherObject);

    ob3 = spy.methodToBeTested();

    assertNotNull(ob3);
}
```

Note that this has a good chance of indicating a code smell. The `method2()` should perhaps be moved into another class, on which A would depend.

Comment: upvote for indicating a code smell. If you need to spy, in 99% of cases you need to refactor your code

Comment: @SarthakNigam then you should *accept* the answer to mark your question as answered. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: sorry didn't know that